# Is there any way to convert c++ gdi+ pen to C# pen

Tags: c#, c++, gdi+

in c++ project,i create a gdi+ pen。c++ code example :

```
long GetPen()
{
  Pen *pen = new Pen(Color.Red);

  return (long)pen; 
}
```

in c# project,i want to use the gdi+ pen create by c++ project。c# code example:

```
[DllImport("xxxx.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetPen();

public void test()
{
   Intptr penptr = GetPen();

   //i want to convert the penptr to C# pen,is there any way?
}
```

Comment: [The C# system libraries already have a `System.Drawing.Pen` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.aspx), and the classes in the `System.Drawing` namespace [provide access to GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.aspx) already. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Yes！The GDI+ pen can only be created by the C++ in the project。The project is about read the emf files.I can only use C++ to get each element of emf files.

Comment: I don't think the Pen class provides any interop mechanism like this... you may need to P/Invoke to GDI+ if you absolutely have to use an unmanaged Pen from C#.  (Oh, and also note that, based on your code, you will need to call back into C++ code to delete the unmanaged Pen.)